# Problem connecting to DocumentDB / MongoDB instance on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I set up a new cluster for MongoDB on AWS and switch off the TLS.

I also set it into the VPS of the server from which I'm trying to connect and opened the inbound `27017` port access in the security group of the cluster.

Then when I tried to connect using the AWS-proposed

```
mongo --host docdb-yyy-mm-dd.cluster-name-of-cluster.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --username <myUser> --password <insertYourPassword>
```

Replacing the `myUser` and `insertYourPassword` with the DB credentials, I get the following error:

```
2021-10-27T15:24:01.548+0000 Error: 301 { ok: 0, errmsg: "Unsupported mechanism", code: 301 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1287
exception: login failed
```

Also, when I try to connect from my local machine via MongoDB compass using

```
mongodb://<userName>:<insertYourPassword>@docdb-yyy-mm-dd.cluster-name-of-cluster.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
```

It simply won't connect.

What can I fix to make it work?

Comment: Re-enable TLS and see if that works